# Objective-C exception handling

Tags: objective-c, exception

I'm trying to figure out how exception handling works in Objective-C. So I'm forcing an exception by performing a selector (boom) which does not exist. When I run it, the application crushes, the exception is not handled properly.  Can somebody show me the proper way of handling exceptions in objective-c?

```
@try{
       [self performSelector:@selector(boom)];
     }
     @catch (NSException *ex) {
         NSLog(@"Error");
     }
```

... And can somebody also show me how to handle exception for the code below. I'm using one instance variable for four different sound effects. After playing, I set the variable to nil. For some reason, the code below crushes the app at times, so I will like to handle that exception. Thanks.

```
- (void) playSound:(NSUInteger) number withDelay:(NSTimeInterval) delay
{
    if(sound == nil)
    {
        NSURL* url;
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1: url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Shuffle" withExtension:@"caf"]; break;
            case 3: url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Clap" withExtension:@"caf"]; break;
            case 4: url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Glass" withExtension:@"caf"]; break;
            case 5: url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Knock" withExtension:@"caf"]; break;
            default: break;
        }

        if (url != nil)
        {
            sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
            [sound setCurrentTime:0];
            [sound prepareToPlay];
            [sound setVolume:1.0];
            [sound performSelector:@selector(play) withObject:nil afterDelay: delay];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not related to Xcode. You could use any IDE, any compiler, whatever - the question is about **Objective-C** exceptions.

Comment: Show us the code where you throw the exception

Comment: for the above code, where do I put the throw before I can try and catch?

Comment: Exceptions in Objective-C are only for exceptional circumstances, and not for regular program flow. They almost always indicate programmer error. You should ideally never have to use at-try and at-catch in an ObjC application, and not in this case either.

Answer (score 2):

*Exception Handling will not solve your problem here,*

If you call `- (void) playSound:(NSUInteger) number withDelay:(NSTimeInterval) delay` from button press events. **Multiple button presses** would lead to this kind of crashes. Because you are using the same AVAudioPlayer variable ***sound** and that same object is used to play sounds **after delays**.A call from other button press could be initiating the sound player, while another one tries to play the sound.

If these are short sound clips (less than 30sec), Without using `AVAudioPlayer` , you better use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`,

You can write a method to delay the start of play, This will let you play multiple sound clips at the  same time without any problem.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shuffle" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
SystemSoundID  soundFileObject;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge_retained CFURLRef) url, &soundFileObject);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
```